# Raspberry Pi webcam server streaming via an IP?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, camera, motion

I developed one webcam server using my Raspberry Pi and Logitech webcam and [Motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome) library. I'm able to view the stream by using Raspberry Pi's IP.

If I use an IP camera instead of a normal webcam, how can I access the stream. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on cameras. In the past, I have successfully done what OP asks by using cameras streaming H.264 over RTP, controlled by RTSP.

In order to do this, an RTP client is required in order to access the camera and get a hold of the stream. I have used [live555](http://www.live555.com). My first try was with openRTSP from CLI.